# Nested <Route> components are not rendering properly in react-redux-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to link React, Redux and the React-Redux-Router in my project, but I am having some difficulty making nested routes work together.

I am trying to have a RegistrationForm component be accessible through a nested route of the parent LoginForm component. However, when I try to nest the routes, my browser does not render anything at `localhost:3000/login/register`

Here is my app structure:

`Root.js` Component

```
import { Redux, React, React-Redux-Router Dependencies etc.} from 'modules'
import LoginForm from './LoginForm'

export default class Root extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
                    <Redirect exact="true" from="/" to="/login"/>
                    <Route exact={true} path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
            </Switch>
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

`LoginForm.js` Component

```
import RegisterForm from './RegisterForm'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class LoginForm extends Component {

 render() {
  const { match } = this.props;
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
             {Some Form Inputs}

            <div>
                Don't have an account? Register now!

                <Link to={match.url + "/register"}>  Register </Link>

                <Route path="/login/register" component={RegisterForm}>
                    // Nothing renders at this Route Path.
            </div> 
        </form>
    )
 }
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginForm))
```

When I attempt this type of nested routing, my browser does not display anything at `localhost:3000/login/register`

When I look at React DevTools, the project structure contains an empty Switch element:

```
<Root>
  <Provider>
    <ConnectedRouter>
      <Router>
        <Switch></Switch> // EMPTY - - No Routes ??
      </Router>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
</Root>
```

However, if I stop trying to nest the routes, and simply place the route for the Registration Component in the `Root.js` Component, the RegistrationForm renders as expected:

```
export default class Root extends Component {
       // This renders everything properly at /login/register
    render() {
        return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
                    <Redirect exact="true" from="/" to="/login"/>
                    <Route exact={true} path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
                    <Route path="/login/register" component={RegisterForm}/>
            </Switch>
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

I apologize for the lengthy question, but I'm not sure why my nested route is not being rendered, and why I must place all of my routes in the main App component for routing to work. It looks like Redux and React-Router have mounted correctly, the console is showing the proper logging of Route Location Changes.

I don't think the parent LoginForm is being lifted properly so that its nested child Route can be rendered, which is why there is an empty `<Switch></Switch>` in Dev Tools.

If anyone who is familiar with React-Router v4 could point me to my mistake, I would really appreciate it! Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Are you importing connect in your LoginForm.js component?

Comment: @AustinStehling I am, let me edit my original post. I just did not want to throw in all of my imports into my code snippet, because it will be a lot. If I did not import, I don't think it would let me compile. As you can see, I am using connect AND withRouter to wrap the LoginForm.js. I also use connect and withRouter in RegisterForm.js

Comment: @ShubhanKhatri Thank you for your link, I understand now. For a nested route, you have to show both components, I was trying to show the forms independently, but using nested routes makes no sense for that, because all parent components must be rendered